# Xcode 15 build error: Assertion failed: (fixups().size() == 2), function initFixup, file Atom.cpp

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15

I'm testing my current project with the Xcode 15 (beta 5) and I'm getting an error that I don't know if it's something new in the Xcode or just an error in the beta version:

```
Assertion failed: (fixups().size() == 2), function initFixup, file Atom.cpp, line 2021.
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I didn't find any other errors like that, any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Is this a C++ or Swift question?

Comment: I can't create an example. It's a large project that just stop working using the new Xcode version. It's fine using Xcode 14

Comment: It's an iOS project that use swift, not a C++ project

Comment: Having the exact same issue - was working fine a few days ago on Xcode 15 and suddenly stopped working with this exact error. Very large project - there's no `Atom.cpp` in our code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode 15 Beta 5 uses a newer linker - you need to use the classic linker to circumvent this for now. See this:

https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues/690#issuecomment-1636180178

Comment: My project has some subprojects, after adding -ld64 to them I started getting new errors that I could fix and finally build. Thank you

Comment: Working good for me thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Worked for me** (SwiftPM firebase):

> A workaround for now would be to use the classic linker by including -ld64 in the 'Other Linker Flags' build settings in Xcode.

Source: https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues/690#issuecomment-1636180178